# R. Get columns from df A whose first row matches elements of df B

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame A without column names like this (the real one has 1808 columns and ~1300000 rows):

A

```
1    1    2    2    6    6    13    13    16    16
0    0    1    0    2    1    0    1    1    0
0    1    2    0    1    2    0    1    0    0
1    1    1    0    1    1    0    2    2    1
```

I also have a data frame B with a single column (the real one has 407 rows), where observations are a subset of row 1 from A:

B

```
2
13
16
```

I want to get a data frame C, with the columns from A that match observations from B. I would get:

A

```
2    2    13    13    16    16
1    0    0    1    1    0
2    0    0    1    0    0
1    0    0    2    2    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `base R` scheme. You can use `which()` to detect the desired values and after that you can do a selection by columns. As you want the first row of `A` you use `A[1,]` and for the values of `B` as it is a column, you can use `B[,1,drop=T]`. Here the code:

```
#Code
A[,which(A[1,] %in% B[,1,drop=T])]
```

Output:

```
  V3 V4 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  2  2 13 13 16  16
2  1  0  0  1  1   0
3  2  0  0  1  0   0
4  1  0  0  2  2   1
```

Some data used:

```
#Data 1
A <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), V2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    V3 = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), V4 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V5 = c(6L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L), V6 = c(6L, 1L, 2L, 1L), V7 = c(13L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), V8 = c(13L, 1L, 1L, 2L), V9 = c(16L, 1L, 0L, 2L), V10 = c(16L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))

#Data 2
B <- structure(list(V1 = c(2L, 13L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks @Duck !. I get this error: "Error in B[, 1, drop = T] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: @Lucas Is your data `B` made with only one column? First try with the data added in the post to understand the logic. Also try changing the code for `B` with `B[, 1]` maybe you have more columns!

Comment: @Lucas Try only with `A[,which(A[1,] %in% B[,1])]` let me know how that goes!